# How can I spy or mock methods in Vue with sinon?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to create a unit test for my app based in Vue and vue-cli with webpack template.

I read Vue documentation, vue-loader, vue-cli and vue-template/webpack (an more!). When I try to make a unit test for my component, I use this.

```
const Constructor = Vue.extend(MovieList)
vm = new Constructor({
    propsData: {
        criteria
    },
    methods: {
        fetch: sandbox.spy()
    }
}).$mount()
```

And test this:

```
expect(vm.fetch).to.be.called
```

But I get this error:

> ✗ should be called fetch
>
> TypeError: { [Function: boundFn] _length: 0 } is not a spy or a call to a spy!
> at assertCanWorkWith (/home/jmanuelrosa/Developer/personales/vue-course/movues/node_modules/sinon-chai/lib/sinon-chai.js:43:19)
> at Assertion. (/home/jmanuelrosa/Developer/personales/vue-course/movues/node_modules/sinon-chai/lib/sinon-chai.js:70:13)
> at Assertion.addProperty (/home/jmanuelrosa/Developer/personales/vue-course/movues/node_modules/chai/chai.js:4240:29)
> at Context. (webpack:///test/unit/specs/MovieList.spec.js:74:39 <- index.js:14910:39)

Answer (score 1):

Never worked with sinon but doc says:

```
sinon.spy(vm, "fetch");
expect(vm.fetch).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.1.0/spies/

Are you calling fetch upon component created? sometimes you need to manually trigger methods.